# ASP.Net button and jQuery PopUp Form

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Below is the code I am using for my Modal Pop Up Form

```
$("[id*=btnFinish").live("click", function () {
    $("#timeLeft").dialog({
        title: "There's Time Left!!",
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
        },
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false
    });
    return false;
});
} else {
    $("#timesUp").dialog({
        title: "Time is up!",
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
        },
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false
    });
}
```

...

```
<div id="timesUp" style="display: none">
    Click proceed to start the first exam module.
    <br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnProce" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="PROCEED" />
</div>
<div id="timeLeft" style="display: none">
You can go back, review your answers and change them if needed. Or you can continue to the next module and click Proceed.
<br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="BACK" />&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="btnProceed" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="PROCEED" />
</div>
```

In my code behind, `div="timeLeft"` as you see holds two buttons `btnProceed` and `btnBack`. `btnProceed` has the same function as `btnProce` in `div="timesUp"`. Now, my problem is when modal pop up for div="timeLeft" is shown and when user clicks `btnBack`, I want the modal pop up to close and execute the code behind. I really don't have idea how to do it.

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using ?

Comment: These are my scripts: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
$("#btnBack").trigger('click');
```

under the if-statement, it should look like this

```
$("[id*=btnFinish").live("click", function () {
    $("#timeLeft").dialog({
        title: "There's Time Left!!",
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
            $("#btnBack").trigger('click');
        },
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false
    });
    return false;
});
} else {
    $("#timesUp").dialog({
        title: "Time is up!",
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
        },
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false
    });
}
```